# When to use tabularx vs. tabular?

Tags: tables, tabularx, best-practices

As mentioned in the title, I was wondering if anyone can point me to a guide on when to use `tabularx` and when to use `tabular` (or `tabular*`).

Based on my limited knowledge and posts like [LaTeX tables with automatic column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352644/latex-tables-with-automatic-column-width) and [When does tabularx decide to break the cell entry instead of reducing the columns separation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489040/when-does-tabularx-decide-to-break-the-cell-entry-instead-of-reducing-the-column), it seems that whenever I am dealing with numbers `tabular` environment is a better choice.  What if I have a combination of text and number in my table?  I wanted to ask community's opinion and best practices to use these environments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341205/what-is-the-difference-between-tabular-tabular-and-tabularx-environments.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  While the post that you mentioned discuss the differences between these environments, I am looking for best practices of using each environment.